# One or more containers do not have resource limits - warning in VS Code Kubernetes tools

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code

After creating the pod-definition.yml file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: myapp-pod
    labels: 
      app: myapp
      type: server
spec:
    containers:
        - name: nginx-container
          image: nginx
```

The linter is giving this warning.

`One or more containers do not have resource limits - this could starve other processes`

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/vscode-kubernetes-tools/vscode-kubernetes-tools/issues/1223

Answer (score 125, accepted):

It is a good practice to declare resource requests and limits for both [memory](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/) and [cpu](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/) for each container. This helps to schedule the container to a node that has available resources for your Pod, and also so that your Pod does not use resources that other Pods needs - therefore the *"this could starve other processes"* message.

E.g. to add resource requests and limits to your example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels: 
    app: myapp
    type: server
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 512Mi
        cpu: "1"
      requests:
        memory: 256Mi
        cpu: "0.2"
```

Comment: Setting CPU limits is not considered good practice by everyone :) https://home.robusta.dev/blog/stop-using-cpu-limits

Answer (score 98):

As you know, that warning comes from the linter in VS Code Extension `ms-kubernetes-tools.vscode-kubernetes-tools`. If you want the linter to disable the warning

```
One or more containers do not have resource limits - this could starve other processes
```

then edit VS Code `setting.json` to look like this:

```
{
    "vs-kubernetes": {
        "disable-linters": ["resource-limits"],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Which (kind of) defeats the purpose of the linter, doesn't it?

Comment: Quite often you're reading other people's code or 3rd party code. It's not up to you to change it. And, even if it's your own code, your team may somehow not want that. The point is, there are plenty of scenarios where you just want to turn that wiggly underlines off from VS Code so that you can have a pleasant reading experience.

Comment: "you just want to turn that wiggly underlines off from VS Code so that you can have a pleasant reading experience"... agreed

Comment: @VincentYin Totally agree. For my case these wiggly lines are quite annoying as I'm intentionally not setting the resource limits as we've already defined default limits for every pod using a LimitRange for the cluster, which means we only need to define resource limits for containers that deviate from the norm.

Comment: And there are times when you want to set a memory limit but not a CPU limit on a container...you don't get credit for setting the mem limit; it still barks about CPU. Those squigglies are maddening. Turns the whole folder, and its parent folders, orange in my VS Code theme.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with an in-line comment ?

Answer (score 2):

I was working with my YAML object files and previously I have every single object in a separated file and I recently noticed that for a "Deployment" object file I have the following linting warning:

`One or more containers do not have resource limits - this could starve other processes`

Before fixing that issue, I decided to refactor my object definition a bit and define more than one object in a single file if they are related. So now I have the same Deployment as before along with a Volume Claim and a Service, everything in the same file.

But then I noted that the linting warning doesn't show up for the Deployment, but it does show up if I delete the Service and Volume Claim from the file, leaving the Deployment alone.

So I suppose the linting code is not taking into account the possibility of having many objects definition per file.

Thanks!